# Howto detect when a file is released

Tags: c#

General information: VS 2010, C#, net.framework 4.0.
brief: Howto detect when a file is released?

Long description

I convert a wav file with lame codec. That process takes some seconds (upto 30 seconds). After the wav file will be converted, I want to delete the source wav file. How to detect when the wav file is released by lame.exe and can be deleted? Please give a method, but without a timer that waiting for 30 seconds and trying to delete (it's bad idea).

Comment: Use [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to watch for changes in a specified directory. You can watch for changes in files and subdirectories of the specified directory. You can create a component to watch files on a local computer, a network drive, or a remote computer.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Do you know if it is capable of detecting when a file is no longer being _read_?  Or will the OP have to detect when the converted file is finished being _written_?

Comment: You can try to delete the file using a try-catch block and, if is not possible, wait for a certain time.

Answer (score 2):

There are example code in MSDN, you can take a reference.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
// Add event handlers.
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
```